# Jenkins project-based security block all user

Tags: jenkins

I set Jenkins global security configuration to using Matrix-based security.
In a project, I set enable "project-based security" and checked "Block inheritance of global authorization matrix.".
I saved before I set permission for any user.
So now nobody can touch this project under Matrix-based security mode.
I set global security configuration to other mode now to access this project.
Is there any way to make that project visible under Matrix-based security mode?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it.
I edit that job's config.xml. It's under jenkins_home/jobs/prject_name.
remove these lines:

```
   <properties>
     <hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
     <blocksInheritance>true</blocksInheritance>
     </hudson.security.AuthorizationMatrixProperty>
   </properties>
```

Restart jenkins and it fixed.